# && || operator interaction

Tags: c++, logical-operators, operator-precedence

I need to know how the logical AND an OR operators are evaluated in a statement. I have found a few sites that try to explain it but I can't make heads nor tails of them. I know I can use braces to order it how I want but i'd like to understand how it works.

for example would

```
if( b1 && b2 || b3 )
```

be evaluated as:

```
(b1 && b2) || b3
```

or as:

```
b1 && (b2 || b3)
```

Comment: These things are well-documented; which resource(s) were consulted first?

Comment: `()` are parentheses, not braces, which are `{}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find in any [operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) that `&&` has higher precedence than `||`, which means it's evaluated as

```
(b1 && b2) || b3
```

Note though that both `&&` and `||` are short-circuiting, which means that `b2` and `b3` don't have to be evaluated. For example, if `b1` evaluates to `false`, `b2` will not be evaluated at all. Also, if `b1 && b2` evaluates to `true`, `b3` won't be evaluated.

Comment: Short-circuiting is very useful to avoid evaluating an expression which could fail, eg. if(x>=0 && myArray[x]...){...}

Answer (score 0):

`&&` and `||` work just like `*` and `+` in this respect.